# How can I utilize threading in my caesar cipher?

Tags: java, multithreading, caesar-cipher

I have this caesar cipher that I made as a project way back 1.5 years ago as a project and I'll be reusing it since I'm tasked to create a program that utilizes threading.

```
byte[] filebyte = new byte[(int) file.length()];

try {
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    fileInputStream.read(filebyte);

    //The characters inside the array are shifted here.
    for (int i = 0; i < filebyte.length; i += 4) {
        filebyte[i] = (byte)((filebyte[i] + key) % 256);
    }

    //Then written back into the file.
    FileOutputStream newfile = new FileOutputStream(file);
    newfile.write(filebyte);
    newfile.close();
    System.out.println("File encrypted successfuly.");
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("File Not Found.");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

My plan currently is to use 4 threads and each thread will encrypt every after 4 characters/bytes as shown below.

Text: Hello World

thread1 - Hor

thread2 - e l

thread3 - lWd

thread4 - lo

However, my problem is how can I make the threads work directly on the file? Instead of each thread taking the file and encrypt it individually, potentially overwriting over each other.

Comment: If you want to operate on `char`s, use a different IO method (some variation of a `Reader`).

Comment: You can perform IO operations before and after the parallel processing, having each thread perform work on part of your `char[]` buffer.

Comment: Would `char[]` work on actual files?

Comment: If you find your current handling of characters to be correct, don't change your IO method.